# Why my binary tree doesn't print anything?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I've been trying to print my binary tree in pre-order and I'm stuck for a while trying to understand why my code doesn't work. I've been trying to debug and it seems that it has to do with my insert function, but still no success. Could you guys help me?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef int KEY;

typedef struct aux
{
    KEY key;
    struct aux* left;
    struct aux* right;
} NODE;

void iniNODE(NODE* root);
NODE* createNode(KEY key);
NODE* insertNODE(NODE* root, KEY key);
bool removeNODE(NODE* root, KEY key);
void printInOrder(NODE* root);
void printPreOrder(NODE* root);
NODE* search(NODE* root, KEY key);

void iniNODE(NODE* root)
{
    root = NULL;
}

NODE* createNode(KEY key)
{
    NODE* newNode = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

NODE* insertNODE(NODE* root, KEY key)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return createNode(key);
    }

    if(key > root->key)
    {
        root->right = insertNODE(root->right, key);
    }
    else if(key < root->key)
    {
        root->left = insertNODE(root->left, key);
    }
    return root;
}

void printPreOrder(NODE* root)
{
    if(root != NULL) return;

    printf("%d | ", root->key);
    printPreOrder(root->left);
    printPreOrder(root->right);
}

NODE* search(NODE* root, KEY key)
{
    if(root->key == key || root == NULL)
    {
        return root;
    }
    if(root->key < key)
    {
        search(root->right, key);
    }

    return search(root->left, key);
}

int main()
{
    NODE NODE1;
    iniNODE(&NODE1);
    insertNODE(&NODE1, 1);
    insertNODE(&NODE1, 2);
    insertNODE(&NODE1, 3);
    insertNODE(&NODE1, 4);
    insertNODE(&NODE1, 5);
    insertNODE(&NODE1, 6);
    insertNODE(&NODE1, 7);
    printPreOrder(&NODE1);
}
```

It's a standard implementation of a binary tree, as it you guys can see in the struct. I compiled the code using gcc and ran on my terminal (Windows 10) and trying to use code blocks(which probably would give the same result, since I'm using the same compiler) and I ran out of ideas.

Comment: Voted to reopen. There was more than just one typo.

Answer (score 1):

Because this:

```
if(root != NULL) return;
```

Should have been this:

```
if(root == NULL) return;
```

And your initialization function doesn't do anything at all with the result being the root node is uninitialized so it prints garbage. Setting `root` to null has no effect because `root` is just a copy of the pointer to `NODE1` so setting it to null has no effect on anything outside of the `iniNODE` function.

The function should look like this:

```
void iniNODE(NODE* root)
{
    root->key = 0;
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I changed in my code, but still doesn't print anything. Could it be other problem? Sorry for asking like this, but I've been trying to find out for a while and nothing came to me.

Comment: @RyuujinWillyWillyLee It works for me, but it has a bug because the root node isn't initialized. I'll edit to show the complete fix.

Answer (score 0):

In this method:

```
void printPreOrder(NODE* root)
{
    if(root != NULL) return;

    printf("%d | ", root->key);
    printPreOrder(root->left);
    printPreOrder(root->right);
}
```

You are checking if the root is not null, and if so, you are directly returning without printing anything. This should be the behavior in case the root is null, not the opposite. Did you mean to say:

```
if(root == NULL) return;
```

**Edit:** Another problem you have is that your `insertNODE` method does not replace your `root` by a value if `root` is null, therefore, even after your call to `createNode(key)`, your `root` is still null. Consider replacing:

```
if(root == NULL)
{
    return createNode(key);
}
```

By:

```
if(root == NULL)
{
    root =  createNode(key);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my code still doens't print anything. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: @RyuujinWillyWillyLee answer updated. Hope this fixes it!

Comment: It makes sense, thanks for the effort, but still doesn't work, I tried to print anything after the insert function with the correction and the execution doesn't reach the print. So I think that the problem still remains at the insert function